# Start timer depending on AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have this task where I have to show data in a big tv screens.
I think I got the hang of it but some "features" or some say bugs appear.
I'm not an expert at any levels, but stuck and don't know where to go. 
Some Code:

```
<?php
    require(db_conn.php);
    $tv_ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $tv_select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT LocationName FROM busyrooms WHERE IpAddress='$tv_ip'");
    $tv_row= mysqli_fetch_row($tv_select);
    $tvname=$dock_row[0];
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Location, Status, Date_Time FROM location_status WHERE Location='$tvname' ORDER BY Date_Time DESC LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql); 
    $sql2=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT parameter_value FROM parameters WHERE parameter_name='Normal_Meeting_time'");
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($sql2);
    $name = $row[0];
    $status_from_table =$row[1];
    $target_time=$row2[0];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/pacemaker_styles.css">
    <title>MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="name"><?=$name ?></div>
  <div id="target">Target</div>
  <div id="target-time"><?=$target_time?></div>
  <div id="status_now"><?=$status_from_table?></div>
  <div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
  <script src="LIB/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      let status_now = document.getElementById('status_now').innerHTML;
      let targetTime = document.getElementById('target-time');
      let dataTargetTime = targetTime.textContent;
      let actualTime = dataTargetTime.split(':').reduce((acc,time) => (60 * acc) + +time);
      let timerVar = setInterval(countTimer, 1000);
      let totalSeconds = 0;
      function countTimer() {
        ++totalSeconds;
        let hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds /3600);
        let minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour*3600)/60);
        let seconds = totalSeconds - (hour*3600 + minute*60);
        if(hour < 10)
          hour = "0"+hour;
        if(minute < 10)
          minute = "0"+minute;
        if(seconds < 10)
          seconds = "0"+seconds;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;
        if(actualTime == totalSeconds){
          document.getElementById('status_now').style.backgroundColor="#cc0000";
          document.getElementById('status_now').style.color="#ffffff";
          document.getElementById('status_now').innerHTML="Delayed Meeting";
        } 
      }
      document.getElementById('status_now').value = status_now;
      setInterval(() => {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'check.php',
          data: {'status': $('#status_now').prop('value')},
          success: function(result) {
            switch (result) {
                case 'ROOM_IN':
                document.getElementById("status_now").innerHTML = "Meeting in progress";
                break;
                
                case 'Room_OUT':
                document.getElementById("status_now").innerHTML = "The room is empty";
                break;

                default:
                document.getElementById("status_now").innerHTML = " There was an error!";
                document.getElementById('status_now').style.backgroundColor="#cc0000";
                break;
            }
          }
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The check.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require ('functions.php'); //check_input comes from here
require ('db_conn.php');

$status = check_input($_POST["status"]);
$tv_ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$tv_select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT LocationName FROM busyrooms WHERE IpAddress='$tv_ip'");
$tv_row= mysqli_fetch_row($tv_select);
$tvname=$tv_row[0];
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Status FROM location_status WHERE Location='$tvname' ORDER BY Date_Time DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql); 
$actual_status =$row[0];

if ($status == "RoomIn") {
    echo "ROOM_IN";
} elseif ($status == "DockOut") {
    echo "ROOM_OUT";
}
?>
```

So the ajax checks the db every second looking for changes.( I think I'm not sure) 
If it gets ROOM_OUT I just want the "status_now" div to say "The room is empty" and not start the timer. 
If it gets Room_In I want to start the timer and say " Meeting in progress" how ever when the target-time is reached I need to change the timer's div background color to red and if they left the room then the first thing happens. Can somebody give me a hint where I gone wrong with this? 
Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Start and stop the interval timer in the success function depending on the result.

Also, to keep from running multiple timers, I check whether `timerVar` is already set before starting the timer again.

Another problem is that `$("#status_now").prop("value")` is not correct. The `value` property only exists in input elements, but `#status_now` is a DIV. Use `.text()` to get the contents of a DIV.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let status_now = document.getElementById('status_now').innerHTML;
  let targetTime = document.getElementById('target-time');
  let dataTargetTime = targetTime.textContent;
  let actualTime = dataTargetTime.split(':').reduce((acc, time) => (60 * acc) + +time);
  let timerVar;
  let totalSeconds = 0;

  function countTimer() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    let hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    let minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour * 3600) / 60);
    let seconds = totalSeconds - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60);
    if (hour < 10)
      hour = "0" + hour;
    if (minute < 10)
      minute = "0" + minute;
    if (seconds < 10)
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;
    if (actualTime == totalSeconds) {
      document.getElementById('status_now').style.backgroundColor = "#cc0000";
      document.getElementById('status_now').style.color = "#ffffff";
      document.getElementById('status_now').innerHTML = "Delayed Meeting";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('status_now').value = status_now;
  setInterval(() => {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'check.php',
      data: {
        'status': $('#status_now').text()
      },
      success: function(result) {
        switch (result) {
          case 'ROOM_IN':
            document.getElementById("status_now").innerHTML = "Meeting in progress";
            clearInterval(timerVar);
            timerVar = null;
            break;

          case 'Room_OUT':
            document.getElementById("status_now").innerHTML = "The room is empty";
            if (!timerVar) {
              timerVar = setInterval(countTimer, 1000);
            }
            break;

          default:
            document.getElementById("status_now").innerHTML = " There was an error!";
            document.getElementById('status_now').style.backgroundColor = "#cc0000";
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

In your PHP, you're using `$status` to produce the output. The result of the query is in `$actual_status`. So it should be:

```
if ($actual_status == "RoomIn") {
    echo "ROOM_IN";
} elseif ($actual_status == "DockOut") {
    echo "ROOM_OUT";
}
```

Comment: What a good advice.This was really helpful thank you. Now the only thing left is to see why the status_now doesn't change when i change data in the db.

Comment: Make sure the AJAX script isn't echoing anything else. Check the Network tab to see the full response.

Comment: Unfortunetly the script is not echoing anything else.

Comment: Maybe there's whitespace, try `switch(result.trim())`. If that doesn't work, add `console.log(result)` to see what it's actually getting.

Comment: I logged it, firstly it gets it right from the db when the page loads, but when i change the data in the db not on the page to ROOM_OUT the page doesn't recognize the change. I think there might be a logical error in the code.
It just keep logging the first thing it gets.

Comment: `$('#status_now').prop('value')` should be `$('#status_now').text()`

Comment: I figured it out, in the script file i need to check the $actual_status var not the $status var. Anyway  you are a good man thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. So what is the AJAX parameter used for?